# Why are the two console.log executed when I click the button even though they aren't inside the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

It is supposed to execute only the function `shuffleCards` when I click the button but instead it also executes the two `console.log()` statements, the one before and after the function.

Why is this happening?

The code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const cardImages = [
  {"text": "A"},
  {"text": "B"},
  {"text": "C"},
  {"text": "D"},
  {"text": "E"},
  {"text": "F"},
]

function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);

  console.log("Cardssssssssss")

  const shuffleCards = () => {
    const shuffledCards = [...cardImages, ...cardImages]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((card) => ({ ...card, id: Math.random() }))
    setCards(shuffledCards);
    setTurns(0)     // understand sort() method
  }  // even though rahom bara lfunction rahom y'atfficha f onclick why  

  console.log("Cards:", cards)

  return (
    <div className="App  text-center p-4 text-white bg-[black] h-[100vh] " >
      <h1  className='text-4xl font-bold  ' >Magic Match</h1>            
      <button
        onClick={shuffleCards}
        className='border-white border border-solid p-1 px-2 mt-4 '
      >
        New Game
      </button>
    </div
```

Comment: can you please share additional details, such as code snippets and error/logs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both console logs are in the component body and the ***entire*** function body of a React function component ***is*** the "render" function. These logs are unintentional side-effects.

You will see both logs occur ***any time*** the component renders for ***any reason at all***.

In this specific case when the button is clicked and the `shuffleCards` callback handler is invoked, it enqueues two state updates to `cards` and `turns` which will trigger a component rerender after they are processed.

Generally you will want to place side-effects into the very appropriately named `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Cardssssssssss");
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency, runs once on component mount

  const shuffleCards = () => {
    const shuffledCards = [...cardImages, ...cardImages]
      .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
      .map((card) => ({ ...card, id: Math.random() }));
    setCards(shuffledCards);
    setTurns(0);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Cards:", cards);
   }, [cards]); // <-- cards dependency, run effect when cards updates

  return (
    <div className="App  text-center p-4 text-white bg-[black] h-[100vh] " >
      <h1  className='text-4xl font-bold  ' >Magic Match</h1>            
      <button
        onClick={shuffleCards}
        className='border-white border border-solid p-1 px-2 mt-4 '
      >
        New Game
      </button>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0):

In react when a component render, all the functions before the `return` are executed, so you are calling shuffleCards() onClick but before all the code

between `function App() {`

and `return (`

got executed,

btw replace `onClick={shuffleCards}` by `onClick={ () => { shuffleCards() } }` to call in only when click !